# Reconfiguring the network interface on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I am changing my configuration from dhcp to static. After running `ifdown`/`ifup` `ifconfig` does not reflect the change. Running `systemctl restart` did not reflect the change.  Rebooting did.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:
    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

`/etc/network/interfaces.d/primary`:
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

DHCP returns:
`address` was 192.168.0.5
`mask` 255.255.255.0
`gateway` 192.168.0.1
`broadcast` 192.168.0.255
`network` 192.168.0.0
`dns-nameservers` 192.168.0.1

`/etc/network/interfaces.d/primary` was edited to:
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    `address` 192.168.0.244
    `mask` 255.255.255.0
    `gateway` 192.168.0.1
    `broadcast` 192.168.0.255
    `network` 192.168.0.0
    `dns-nameservers` 192.168.0.1

upon save ran 
    sudo ifdown eth0
    sudo ifup eth0

Afterwards `ifconfig` still returned the 192.168.0.5 address

I tried again using the `--force` option on `ifup` with the same result.

I then tried `systemctl restart networking.service` and `ifconfig` still reported the 192.168.0.5 address.

None of these commands appeared to apply the change in the configuration file. Rebooting, however, did apply the change correctly so I believe the static configuration I created is correct.

Comment: First, you're just telling us a story about a problem, NOT describing a problem. What do all those changed lines look like? What are the results of the commands you ran?

Comment: Please don't post additional information in the comments field. Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1044543/edit ) your post to add the new information, and format it properly with the `{}` button